# Optional logging http requests and response

Tags: c#, http, delegates, .net-7.0

Could somebody describe how achieve those goal:
I have http client with methods. Sometimes server start send strange data, and I need to capture request and response.
Injecting logger to every method in httpClient sounds awful. I need this log sometimes and amount of log information can be huge. So i need to switch logging for precise httpclient method capture data i.e. for a day and turn off log's without recompiling application.
What I'm thought I can register delegate handler which get as option data from appsettings json where I store something which can identify my methods that should be logged.
I think somebody already did that. And maybe I can use ready-made solution. If not I can't completely invent a way how map data from appsettings.json to info that delegate handler has. I mean what way i should store in example full URL or maybe some another data on what i can identify what type of http request sended.

Comment: Are you familiar with `ILogger<T>` and the Microsoft logging abstraction in general?

Comment: How do you discriminate "strange" data from "legit" data? Maybe you can simply do a sanity check and log when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

> Injecting logger to every method in httpClient sounds awful. I need this log sometimes and amount of log information can be huge.

What you need is an application wide setting called 'debug', which you can enable/disable when starting the application.

If it is enabled, it will log all output. So you can enable it for a day, then reboot your application with the parameter disabled. You can also re-use this for other potential problem areas.

Alternatively, you can build conditional statements in the return method; if the output is not exactly X, then log it.

Comment: I think conditional statements is not good idea because  it wires my hands. If I want to add to log capture new method I should create log part in code.
Also idea with debug sounds good but it will start logging every response and request. I'm trying to achieve precise logging of one or maybe two method not all of them.

Comment: Well, those are your two options. Either you log everything in a certain time period, or you log specific things in a time period.